# I Need Help Positioning A Navigation Div

Tags: html, position

I have a very specific problem that I can't seem to solve. I am trying to position a logo (img tag inside an anchor tag) to the left of my navigation div and the other three links on the right side of the navigation div. I am also trying to align both the image and the links vertically in the middle (I have tried verticle-align). Here is the code:

```css
body {
  min-width: 1200px;
}
a.nav {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#header {
  background-color: black;
}
#headtop {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: right;
}
#logo {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 1px solid #00ffff;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="headtop">
    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="logo.jpg" alt="Home" id="logo">
    </a>
    <a href="about.html" class="nav">About</a>
    <a href="gallery.html" class="nav">Gallery</a>
    <a href="contact.html" class="nav">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

So first, I set the minimum width, so that the page collapses into a scroll bar as soon as it gets to the set width. I want the headtop to have a height of about 68px. But when I set the height, I still cannot vertical align the text or the logo. I tried adding padding-top to the links, and it does nothing. They stay stuck to the top of the page. I even tried setting the padding for headtop, which worked, but when I collapsed the page, there was a section of white because for some reason the header background didn't stretch across the entire page. Why are my links stuck to the top of the page and why can't I set the padding without affecting the width of headertop?

Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Set a height on the #header and use line-height equal to the height.  (e.g. `header {height: 50px;} #logo {line-height: 50px;} a {line-height: 50px;}`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change your HTML like this to get the image out of the nav container (I have added an image for displaying purposes)

```
<div id="header"> <a href="index.html">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/5/57/CBC_Logo_1966-1974.svg/618px-CBC_Logo_1966-1974.svg.png" alt="Home" id="logo" />
    </a>

    <div id="headtop"> <a href="about.html" class="nav">About</a>
 <a href="gallery.html" class="nav">Gallery</a>
 <a href="contact.html" class="nav">Contact</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Now, change your CSS like this so you can vertical align items and have all elements displayed just as you want:

```
body {
}
#headtop {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right:20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
a {
    margin:0 20px;
    color:#fff
}
#header {
    background-color: black;
    position:relative;
    height:68px
}
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#logo {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    border: 1px solid #00ffff;
    position:relative
}
```

Notice that I took off the min-width you had (but you can add it if you want). Other than this, I just added a `position:relative` property to the header and then use the [**transform property**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Syntax) for the items you wanted to align vertically.

I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L96bevvs/) so you can play around with it

Comment: This worked perfectly. Line height worked for the links but I tried your solution and it was significantly more effective. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help :) . If it was useful for you, please mark the answer as accepted so other users can benefit from it